# Why is gulp compass throwing out TypeError: dest.on is not a function in my Windows 7 environment

Tags: node.js, gulp, compass

I have installed gulp and  some other packages in the root directory of my project in Visual Studio, Windows 7. I'm find that whenever I run the command gulp watch or gulp compass watch I get the following error:

```
C:\MyProject>gulp compass watch
[11:03:53] Using gulpfile C:\MyProject\gulpfile.js
[11:03:53] Starting 'compass'...
[11:03:53] 'compass' errored after 6.09 ms
[11:03:53] TypeError: dest.on is not a function
at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe         (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\no
de_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:516:8)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\MyProject\gulpfile.js:23:10)
at module.exports     (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask     (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (C:\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:
20
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:469:11)
```

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
// Include Our Plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('sass');
var compass = require('compass');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var config = {
    bootstrapDir: 'node-modules/bootstrap-sass',
    publicDir: 'Content',
};
// Pipe boostrap-sass to main css directory
gulp.task('css', function() {
     gulp.src('Content/scss/bootstrap-app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: [config.bootstrapDir + '/assets/stylesheets'],
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.publicDir + '/css'));
});

// Compile with Compass
gulp.task('compass', function() {
  return gulp.src('Content/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
        //  config_file: 'node_modules/compass/test/config.rb',
          css: 'css',
          sass: 'scss'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Content/css'));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('Content/scss/*.scss', ['compass']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['compass', 'watch']);
```

Any help on this much appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install and require `gulp-compass`, not `compass`.

Comment: Thanks @Louis, I did that which worked but now getting a new error: events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. I suspect I will need to open a new thread for this but would be great to get answers here.